# Find minimum number of swap needed for move all 0's to end of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;

ll swapCount(ll arr[], ll n)
{

    ll count = 0;
    ll lastNonZeroElementIndex = 0;

    for (ll i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        if (arr[i]) {
            lastNonZeroElementIndex = i + 1;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return lastNonZeroElementIndex - count;
}

int main()
{

    ll t, n;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        /* code */
        cin >> n;
        ll arr[n];
        for (ll i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
        cout << swapCount(arr, n) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Order should be in-place.
>
> What I am doing is, I am storing count of non-zero element and index of last non-zero element. And returning the difference of these two.
>   can you tell me where I am making mistake?

[Problem Statement](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CODEM3/)

Comment: `ll arr[n];` is not valid C++. Array sizes need to be constant expressions.

Comment: What makes you think you are making a mistake?

Comment: I coudn't get it where I am making mistake. I run this code on spoj. I am getting wrong answer.

Comment: Then you should learn to test your code yourself, and discover failure cases. I'll help you this time: `[01]`. Next time I'll vote to close.